# Segmentation fault on function call

Tags: c, function, segmentation-fault

I am trying to create a simulation of a stochastic queue system. The thing is that when running the file, I get a segmentation fault as soon as it tries to call update(). I figured it's a stack problem because the code in the function runs fine but since I am not very experienced with C I'd like your help too. Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <limits.h>

#define MAXCLIENTS 11
#define COUNTER_LIMIT 80000000
#define MEAN_DIFFERENCE 0.0000001

char servers_enabled;           
int state = 0;              
float p[MAXCLIENTS];            
float p_help_a[MAXCLIENTS];
float p_help_b[MAXCLIENTS];     
int arrivals = 0;               
int arrival_a[MAXCLIENTS];      
int arrival_b[MAXCLIENTS];
long int count = 0;             
float lambda[3]={0.5,1.0,1.5};  
float mi_a = 2,mi_b = 0.5;      
float gamma_a = 0,gamma_b = 0,gamma_ratio=0; 
float p_b_ab,p_a,p_b,p_a_ab;            
double E = 0,lastE = 0.1;                   

void arrive(char queue_enabled) {       
    ++arrivals;
    switch (queue_enabled) {
    case 'a' :
        ++arrival_a[state];
        break;
    case 'b' :
        ++arrival_b[state];
        break;
    }
    ++count;
    if (state<MAXCLIENTS)
        ++state;
}

void depart() {     
    ++count;
    --state;
}

float randomize() {
    float result;
    srand(time(NULL));
    result = (float) ((float)rand()/INT_MAX);
    return result;
}

void update(FILE *input,FILE *output, FILE *helper) {   
    int i;
    if (count%50000 == 0) {
        gamma_a=0;
        gamma_b=0;
        for (i=0;i<MAXCLIENTS;i++) {
            p_help_a[i] = (float) (arrival_a[i]/arrivals);
            p_help_b[i] = (float) (arrival_b[i]/arrivals);
            p[i] = p_help_a[i]+p_help_b[i];
            gamma_a += p[i]*mi_a;
            gamma_b += p[i]*(arrival_b[i]/arrivals);
            if (E != 0)
                lastE = E;
            E = 0;
            E += i*p[i];
        }
        gamma_a-=p_help_b[1]*mi_a-p_help_a[0];
        if (gamma_b != 0.0)
            gamma_ratio = gamma_a/gamma_b;
        fprintf(output,"throughput_a = %f   | throughput_b = %f     | throughput ratio = %8.6f",gamma_a,gamma_b,gamma_ratio);
        fprintf(output,"    | E = %f    | Pli8os Gegonotwn = %ld\n",E,count);
    }
    //count++;
    fprintf(input,"p_a[%2d] = %.10f p_b[%2d] = %.10f \n",i,p_help_a[i],i,p_help_b[i]);
    fprintf(input,"p = %f \n",p[i]);
    fprintf(helper,"gamma_a= %f    gamma_b= %f    gamma_ratio = %8.6f ",gamma_a,gamma_b,gamma_ratio);
    fprintf(helper,"    E= %f      count= %ld \n",E,(count-1));
}

int main() {

    int i,j,k;      
    FILE *input,*output,*helper;

    input=fopen("first.txt","w");
    output=fopen("second.txt","w");
    helper=fopen("third.txt","w");


    for (i=0;i<3;i++) { 
        fprintf(input,"Ruthmos Afiksewn (lambda) =   %1.1f\n\n",lambda[i]);
        fprintf(output,"Ruthmos Afiksewn (lambda) =   %1.1f\n\n",lambda[i]);
        fprintf(helper,"Ruthmos Afiksewn (lambda) =   %1.1f\n\n",lambda[i]);
        p_a=lambda[i]/(lambda[i]+mi_a);                      p_a_ab=lambda[i]/(lambda[i]+mi_a+mi_b); 
        p_b=lambda[i]/(lambda[i]+mi_b);     
        p_b_ab=(lambda[i]+mi_a)/(lambda[i]+mi_a+mi_b); // ????
        for (j=1;j<=10;j++) {       
            fprintf(input,"--------------------------\n\n");
            fprintf(input,"Katofli (threshold) =   %d\n\n",j);
            fprintf(input,"--------------------------\n\n");
            fprintf(output,"--------------------------\n\n");
            fprintf(output,"Katofli (threshold) =   %d\n\n",j);
            fprintf(output,"--------------------------\n\n");
            fprintf(helper,"--------------------------\n\n");
            fprintf(helper,"Katofli (threshold) =   %d\n\n",j);
            fprintf(helper,"--------------------------\n\n");

            for (k=0;k<(MAXCLIENTS-1);k++) {
                /******************/
            }
            servers_enabled = 'a';
            while(count<=COUNTER_LIMIT && fabs(E-lastE)>=MEAN_DIFFERENCE) {
                if (state == 0) {
                    arrive('a');
                    update(input,output,helper);
                } else
                switch (servers_enabled) {
                    case 'a' :
                        if ((state <= j) && randomize() <= p_a) {
                            arrive('a');
                            update(input,output,helper);
                        } else {
                            depart();
                            update(input,output,helper);
                        }
                        if (state > j)
                            servers_enabled = 'b';
                        break;
                    case 'b' :
                        if (state == 1) 
                            if (randomize() < p_b) {
                                arrive('b');
                                update(input,output,helper);
                            } else {
                                depart();
                                update(input,output,helper);
                            } else if (randomize() < p_a) {
                                arrive('b');
                                update(input,output,helper);
                            } else if (randomize() < p_b_ab) {
                                depart();
                                update(input,output,helper);
                            } else {
                                depart();
                                update(input,output,helper);
                                if (state <= j)
                                    servers_enabled = 'a';
                            }
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    fclose(input);
    fclose(output);
    fclose(helper);
    return 0;
}
```

Please don't mind the rest of the errors. I am currently in the debugging stage, so any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Welcome to SO please be more specific (did u try gdb or something yet) and also don't expect to put tons of code here and have us become human logic compilers for you.

Comment: +1 for nice code style and indentation :)

Comment: Yes I am sorry for not mentioning that, I tried debugging it but it didn't bring any results. I will make a simplified version of the code and repost it soon. Thanks for the quick reply.

Comment: Agree with the other user on the coding style, usually when you ask questions you want to narrow the issues. With gdb you can usually tell whats going wrong because on the segfault if you call backtrace you can see the stack (to check if its corrupted) and also inspect any variables you might be using for bad pointers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is in line:

```
fprintf(input,"p_a[%2d] = %.10f p_b[%2d] = %.10f \n",i,p_help_a[i],i,p_help_b[i]);
```

Here `i` is uninitialized and `p_help_a[i]` leads to access violation.

Comment: dont see a problem, there is

      for (i=0;i<MAXCLIENTS;i++) {} unless if (count%50000 != 0) {}

Comment: Yep, that fixed it! Thanks everyone for your time :)

Comment: @user. It matters only in case the condition is true `count%50000 == 0`. Actually I have just copypasted the code, tried to run it and got this exception. I really don't understand why in this world the questioner has not caught this bug :-)

Comment: @tyz - consider checking for that fopen result too

Answer (score 1):

```
input=fopen("first.txt","w");
output=fopen("second.txt","w");
helper=fopen("third.txt","w");
```

what if they are null?